# Observale function with pipe operator

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

How to use map, switchMap or another operator with a function that returns an observable. The goal is to map the result of the observable function and use that value when subscribing to another observable.

```
getBackendResponse(param1, param2): Observable {
  return this.service.getResponse(param1, param2)
}

this.anotherService.useData$.pipe(
        map(data => return getBackendResponse(data.param1, data.param2))
).subscribe(responseFromBackend => {
   console.log("response", reponseFromBackend) 
})
```

Comment: you can use switchMap

Comment: Yes, use `switchMap` instead of `map`, have you tried it yet?

Comment: Yes, the switchMap operator works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getBackendResponse(param1, param2): Observable {
  return this.service.getResponse(param1, param2)
}

this.anotherService.useData$.pipe(
        switchMap(data => return getBackendResponse(data.param1, data.param2))
).subscribe(responseFromBackend => {
   console.log("response", reponseFromBackend) 
})
```